# mmap with map_ANON for saving large amount data

Tags: c++, mmap

I am working on a project which requires to generate a huge amount of data (i.e hundreds of gigabytes) and process them later on. Currently, I am using C++ and I'd like to use mmap() to create some virtual memory to keep the data. The obvious way to do it is to create a file and use mmap() to map let's say 100GB to the file, then we should be able to read/write data from the mapped memory. Something like this:

```
    int file = open("disk_cache", O_RDWR|O_CREAT, 0644);
    lseek (file,//100GB, SEEK_SET);
    write (file, "", 1);

    auto* mapPtr = (unsigned*)mmap(nullptr, //100GB,  PROT_WRITE|PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, file, 0);
    if ( mapPtr == MAP_FAILED) {
        perror("mmap");
        return ;
    }
    Generate_data(mapPtr); \\ write/generate data here; 
    Process_data(mapPtr);  \\ read/access data here; 
    if (munmap(mapPtr, //100GB) == -1) {
        perror("mmap:");
        return ;
    }
    close(file);
    if( remove("disk_cache") != 0 ){
       perror("remove the file:");
    }
```

The above code works fine, but it just looks a bit redundant that I have to create a file and remove it later. I am thinking whether I can MAP_ANON flag to map the data, so I tried somthing like this:

```
    auto* mapPtr = (unsigned*)mmap(nullptr,  //100GB ,  PROT_WRITE|PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED|MAP_ANON|MAP_NORESERVE, -1, 0);
    if ( mapPtr == MAP_FAILED) {
        perror("mmap");
        return ;
    }
```

It works fine until the data exceed 64 GB (since I am running this on a server which has 64 GB Mem), My questions are as follows:

(1)It seems like MAP_ANON keeps all the data on Mem, not disk? I wonder why this happened? is there any way to avoid it? I thought MAP_ANON would keep all the data in dev/zero, we can safely store/access data from there.

(2)Also, I am using multiple threads(i.e. 32 cores)to generate/access data. For mmap(), random accessing data is very efficient. But storing/writing data to the memory seems to be slower. I did some quick experiments, it seems like ofstream is faster than mmap() especially when the data is larger than Mem. I feel like maybe I did something wrong with mmap(). Are there any things I need to take care of when using mmap() writing/storing data that are larger than Mem? What's the best way to do it?

Any helps would be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: you can actually delete the file and keep using it. then you have a "file" storage, but it will release the storage when the last valid fd on it is close, thus when you call close. You should also pay attention to synchronization in multithreaded environement.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yeah. As I said, we can definitely do that. I just wonder if MAP_ANON still keeps all the data in Mem. If so, why do we need this flag? It seems like we can use a global variable or malloc, and pass a reference/pointer to child threads. As long as, we take care of each thread, it should work. There must be a reason why this flag exists.

Comment: what do you call memory? actually, the data needs to exist "somewhere" thus it is in memory, but can eventually be swapped on disk.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. For the memory, I mean RAM. Since our server only has 64GB RAM, it can't fit all the data (i.e. Up to hundreds of GB) in RAM. That's why we decide to use mmap() to keep the data on the disk and read it whenever we need it. I thought MAP_ANON would open some memory on the disk for us, so we can use it and don't need to worry about extending/deleting the file after we finished. But apparently, I was wrong, MAP_ANON still allocates all the data on RAM, not the disk. When the data exceed 64 GB, it will be killed by OMM.